# Material UI custom TextField dosn't work with Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield, yup

I'm trying to use my custom TextField in my RegisterForm with Yup but he's dosnt work.
All time I have a message "⚠ Champ obligatoire." after click on Submit I don't understand why but is good with a simple input.

[image]

**RegisterPage.js**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Button from "../../lib/Button";
import TextField from "../../lib/TextField";
import * as yup from "yup";

const SignupSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required("⚠ Champ obligatoire."),
});

export default function Home() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors, watch } = useForm({
    validationSchema: SignupSchema,
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
  console.log(errors);

  return (
    <div style={styles.inputForm}>
      <p>Inscription</p>

      <form style={{ marginTop: "40%" }} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label style={styles.label} htmlFor="firstName">
          Prénom
        </label>
        <TextField
          style={styles.input}
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="Toto"
          type="text"
          ref={register}
        />
        <br />
        {errors.firstName && (
          <p style={styles.error}>{errors.firstName.message}</p>
        )}
        <br />

        <Button
          style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
          type="submit"
          onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          Termine ton incription
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My CustomTextField

**CustomTextfield.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function CustomField({ InputLabelProps = {}, ...props }) {
  return (
    <TextField
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, ...InputLabelProps }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

CustomField.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default CustomField;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-ui-custom-textfield-composition-un5iv?codemirror=1
1 error with useRef but I dont use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `inputRef` instead of `ref` on `TextField`. `ref` will be applied to the outermost element which will be the `div` rendered by `FormControl`; and this won't be any help with the yup integration. `inputRef` will forward the ref to the `input` element.

```
        <TextField
          style={styles.input}
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="Toto"
          type="text"
          inputRef={register}
        />
```

[image: Edit Material UI - Custom TextField (composition)]

Related documentation: https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props

Comment: it was that ! Thank You !